# Table sort doesn't work when including PHP file in HTML

Tags: php, html

I made PHP file that has a sortable table. I did it following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlJVt3rTj1Q

The php-page works well, but when I include it to my html-file it doesn't find the path when I try sorting the table through my index.html file.

PHP file is in the "includes" folder that is under the folder where my index.html file is. When I try to sort it, browser tries to find it through this path: `localhost/index.html?order=games&&sort=DESC`. When I try it through the php page it works because the path is `localhost/includes/goaliegamestats.php?order=games&&sort=DESC`

How do I fix this problem?

```
<?php
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

if(isset($_GET['order'])){
  $order = $_GET['order'];
}
else {
  $order = 'points DESC, goals';
}
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
  $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}
else {
  $sort = 'DESC';
}

$result = $conn->query("
    SELECT
      SUM(playergamestats.dressed) AS games
    FROM players 
    INNER JOIN playergamestats
    ON players.playerid=playergamestats.playerid 
    WHERE players.position = 'MV'
    GROUP BY playergamestats.playerid
    ORDER BY $order $sort");

$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    $sort == 'DESC' ? $sort = 'ASC' : $sort = 'DESC';
  echo "
  <table id='playerstatstable' class='tablesort'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href='?order=games&&sort=$sort'>O</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
  // Table body content  
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td class='statcol'>" . $row['games'] . "</td>
          </tr>";
  }
  echo "
    </tbody>
  </table>";
 }
 ?>   

<div id="pelaajatilastot" class="tabpane">
  <?php 
   include 'includes/goaliestatstable.php'; echo "<br />";?>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML cannot render PHP. So in order to make your goaliestatstable.php work, you need to first convert your index.html to index.php.

Comment: Is there another way to sort table thats content is from database source? I tried JS and jQuery, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try jquery datatables https://datatables.net/

Comment: Please remember that when you just state _"it didn't work"_, you're only telling us that _you_ couldn't get it to work. That statement should _always_ be followed by an explanation of what actually happened.

Comment: I solved it by using JS array and made the sorting with JS. First I tried to sort the PHP echoed table using JS, but when I had multiple tables done with PHP none of them worked. Then I got the sorting working using PHP code, but when I had multiple tables on a website only the first table worked.